# How can I evaluate $\int \frac1{2 + \sqrt{x + 1}} dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I find the integral $$\int \frac1{2 + \sqrt{x + 1}} dx$$

Comment: An easier way is to let the whole denominator =y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=t^2-1$ so that $dx=2t\,dt$.  Then,

$$\int \frac1{2+\sqrt{x+1}}\,dx \overbrace{=}^{x=t^2-1}\int \frac{2t}{2+t}\,dt$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: NICE APPROACH! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: I can vote but it doesn't update it I think I need to have at least 15 reputations